# vector equation of line

Tags: geometry, 3d

If I write equation as: $r-a=k(b-r)$ ,then equation becomes $r=\frac{(a+kb)}{(1+k)}$.While equation is $r=a+k(b-a)$
Now are these two vector equations different or same. Please assume $r,a,b$ as vectors,i.e. arrow above them

Comment: IF the equation is "r- a= k(b- r)" as you write, then r- a= kb- kr so that r+ kr= r(1+ k)= a+ bk and then r= (a+ bk)/(1+ k).

Comment: IF the equation is "r- a= k(b- r)" as you write, then r- a= kb- kr so that r+ kr= r(1+ k)= a+ bk and then r= (a+ bk)/(1+ k).  I don't know what you mean by "While equation is r= a+ k(b- a)".  That would be correct only if the original equation were "r- a= k(b- a)".

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbf r = \frac {\mathbf a+k\mathbf b}{1+k}\\
\mathbf r = \frac {\mathbf a(1+k)+k(\mathbf b-\mathbf a)}{1+k}\\
\mathbf r =  \mathbf a + \frac{k}{1+k} (\mathbf b-\mathbf a)\\
$

Now $k$ is any scalar.  And $\frac{k}{1+k}$ is just as easily any scalar.

The equations are eqiuvalent.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the result is a linear combination of two constant vectors then you have a vector equation of a line.

For example the line between two points *A* and *B* is

$$\mathbf{r} = (1-t) \mathbf{a} + t\, \mathbf{b} 
\\ = \mathbf{a} +t\, (\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a})$$

But also the line from point *A* with direction $\mathbf{e}$ is

$$\mathbf{r} =  \mathbf{a} + s\, \mathbf{e} $$
but if $s = t\, \| \mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a} \|$ then the above is identical to the first expression.

Even if the scalar multiplier of the linear combination is non linear quantity like

$$\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{a} +\frac{u}{1+u}\, (\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a})$$ you can always make a substitution $t = \frac{u}{1+u}$ to a single value to get back to the equation of the line.

In summary, a line is a linear combination of two points with the general expression

$$ \mathbf{r} = \lambda(t)\, \mathbf{a} + \mu(t)\, \mathbf{b} $$ if $\lambda(t)$ and $\mu(t)$ are scalar function of a single parameter $t$.